# RabbitMQ **WARNING** Generated by docker-entrypoint.sh

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am running a RabbitMQ service inside a Linux Docker container from Windows 10, and in an attempt to reconfigure the default ports of the service, the following warning log message had been generated: "**WARNING: 'docker-entrypoint.sh' generated/modified the RabbitMQ configuration file, which will no longer happen in 3.9 and later! (https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/pull/424)**."
I had changed the rabbitmq.config file variable **management.tcp.port** to the new preferred port, along with the port mapping within the docker-compose.yaml file, as advised.
The warning results in the inability to alter the ports at which RabbitMQ services can be accessed, as the docker-entrypoint.sh file reconfigures the changes that I had carried out in the rabbitmq.config file back to the default values. Could anyone provide me with pointers to overcome this issue?

Many thanks!

Comment: After taking a quick look at the entrypoint3.8.sh file, it looks like that version will override environment variables in the event that it doesn't find a config file. This is the behavior that will no longer be the case in 3.9. My first guess is that there is an error in your configuration file, and that it's getting re-written as a result. That is where I would start looking.

Comment: @CharlesDesbiens thank you for the quick answer! I took a look at the configuration file that I am using, and it seems as if there are no errors within. The variables that are set are listeners.tcp.default and management.tcp.port. I had cross referenced the RabbitMQ website for the correct syntax, and also restarted the service. Unfortunately, the warning remains. Would an absence of unset variable(s) inside the config file cause such an issue?

Comment: I can't really answer this effectively myself. If you look at the source code for the entrypoint (https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/master/docker-entrypoint-3.8.sh), the condition you're interested in is at line 300. The "$shouldWriteConfig" variable is set to true by something, which causes the script to write a fresh config file from the defaults.

Comment: worst case scenario, if you can't upgrade to 3.9, and you can't stop it from overriding your config with a fresh default, you can also make your own image that uses rabbitmq as the base, and simply overwrite the entrypoint. Just copy the old entrypoint and remove the parts that are causing the error. This should be an absolute last resort though, since it's easy to break something when doing something like this, and it can cause maintenance problems going forward.